# Dar acceso a una tabla de una base de datos en SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Alguien sabe,¿Como dar permisos completos a una tabla de una base de datos en SQL SEVER?
Ejemplo: Tengo el usuario: pruebas_1 y quiero que solo tenga permisos completos a la tabla [GUIAS] de una base de datos, para que pueda hacer (insert, delete, update, select).

Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para dar esos permisos a una tabla en particular, tienes que usar diferentes `GRANT`s:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.GUIAS TO pruebas_1;
GRANT INSERT ON dbo.GUIAS TO pruebas_1;
GRANT UPDATE ON dbo.GUIAS TO pruebas_1;
GRANT DELETE ON dbo.GUIAS TO pruebas_1;
```